# How to apply law of demeter using Service objects pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm studying design patterns and I've came across with the following code.

```
class CreateOrderService
  def initialize(organization, order_params)
    @organization = organization
    @order_params = order_params
  end

  private

  def not_exists?
    existent_order.blank?
  end

  def existent_order
    @existent_order ||= organization.orders.with_external_id(external_id).first
  end

  def create
    some code to create an order...
  end

  attr_reader :organization, :order_params
end
```

Does this method 'existent_order' violate the law of Demeter?
Would it be correct to put this method into the organization's model?

```
def any_external_orders?(id)
  orders.with_external_id(id).exists?
end
```

Comment: If `external_id` is unique column you should be able to use `.find_by(external_id: external_id)` instead. Does not fix the law of demeter violation but reads better and gives a query with a limit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `with_external_id` is a method or a scope that uses a `where`, it should return an empty active record association if there aren't any. Calling `first` on that will return `nil` and calling `blank?` on nil is perfectly fine. This doesn't really assume the `blank?` in `not_exists?` knows anything about the orders specifically, but that it generally knows how active record works. I think it's fine.

Comment: Isn't it wrong to access orders from organizations? Law of Demeter doesn't allow to access an object C from a B

Comment: You're not really asking orders anything through organization though. Exercising active record relations is maybe academically breaking the law of Demeter, but this would only break if you removed that association. My feeling is that if you do that, you'll have other things to worry about.

Comment: Also, in your proposed solution, that code is really `self.orders.with_external_id(id).exists?` so not really different. You can see how active record forces you to do this. I think by making associations, you're accepting a certain level of dependency that warrants a relaxed view of the law of Demeter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `existent_order` has violated the law of Demeter:

`organization` is expected to have `orders`, and then `orders` is expected to respond with a method `with_external_id`, the service also know exactly what to feed to `with_external_id`. There is too much information that a method know. Things will get worse if model `Order` change its methods (i.e. `with_external_id`).

Putting the method out of the service is definitely a better choice.

Comment: Do you think is right the way I did? Creating a method inside organization model

Comment: Yes, even tho we're still not yet cut all the looses, it makes the service know less and therefore it's safer.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create multiple associations between two models:

```
class Organization
   has_many :orders, after_add: :set_last_order!
   belongs_to :last_order, class_name: 'Order'

   def set_last_order!(order)
     self.update!(last_order: order)
   end

   def last_order?
     !!last_order
   end
end
```

This would allow you to clean up the law of demeter violation, and also gives a better distribution of responsibilities.

Additionally don't overuse the ActiveSupport `.blank?` method. Its for testing user input strings.

You can use simple boolean casting to test for nil or the `.nil?` method.

```
def not_exists?
  !!existent_order
  # or
  !existent_order.nil?
end
```